# Multiple functions in a single .m file but only receiving answer for 1 function

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

```
    function d = f(x)
 Vi = 0
 Vf = 25
 df = -150
 d = (Vf^2-Vi^2)/(2*df)
end

% Using this kinematic equation we can solve for the time 
% after converting the measuerments again and plugging them
% into the equation 
function t1 = g(x)
Vi = 25
Vf2 = 5
d2 = - 2.5
t1 = (Vf2-Vi)/d2   
end
% Finding deceleration of truck using kinematic equation. 
function d2 = h(x)
vF3 = 5
t2 = 8
a3 = -2.5
d2 = (vF3*t2)-(0.5*a3*(t2^2))
end
```

I'm new to MATLAB and do not know what to do, I have to make 3 equations that contain more than one variable solving for an unknown, and when I click run it only solves the first function.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple functions in a single `.m` file if you are expecting to use them. In you case, you should have a different `.m` file for each function, and each function name must be the same to the file name.

Multiple functions are allowed in the same `.m` file, but those "extra" functions are private, and can only be used by the "main" function.

Some reading from [Matworks functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) and [function files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html).